# Is using objects without invoking variable PSR compatible?

Tags: php, code-formatting, psr-2

Let's say I want to use `someClass` only once per method. Is such style is PSR compatible?

```
class Foo
{

    public function myMethod($x)
    {
        // ... code ...

        $data = (new someClass())->getSomething($x);

        // ... code ...
    }

}
```

Comment: `php-cs-fixer` says that's psr-2 compatible; you can also use tools such as http://www.webcodesniffer.net/onlinecodesniffer.php

Answer (score 0):

PSR-2, while dictating style for the sake of readability, doesn't really dictate whether or not what you're asking is acceptable, at least according to my understanding of it.

What I would say, though, is that if you're planning to invoke a method from someClass, what I would consider far more readable would be using the scope resolution operator, like so, which removes the requirement of instantiating the object using the 'new' keyword:

```
$data = someClass::getSomething($x);
```

This is functionally equivalent to your syntax, but more readable.

Comment: static methods are not equivalent to object methods at all. you don't invoke constructor, destructor and you can't use `$this` in such context